# PYTHON3 python my interpreter inform to me that has numpy but when I execute my entire code print wrong message

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.std(arr)
1.4142135623730951
>>>
```

my interpreter print correct answer
but my entire code

```
import numpy

def addarr(N,K,score):
    arr=[]
    a=10000
    this = int(N)-int(K)+1

    for j in range(0,this):
        for i in range(j,j+int(K)):
            arr.append(score[i])
            print(i)
        print("asdfasdfasdfasfasdf")
        print(arr)
        b = numpy.std(arr)

        if a>b:
            a=b
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NandK = input()
    N, K = NandK.split()

    string = input()
    score =[]
    score = string.split()
    print(score)

    print(len(score))
    answer = addarr(N,K,score)
    print(answer)
```

My entire code print wrong message about numpy

```
   b = numpy.std(arr)
['1', '2', '3']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3242, in std
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 140, in _std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 107, in _var
    arrmean = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, keepdims=True)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

how can I fix it..
I already install "numpy" with pip3

I using the python3 and my version is 3.7

I have been try import numpy as np but It isnt working too.

It is my INPUT

```
5 3
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Python 3.7 is still pretty new. How certain are you that your libraries are compatible with Python 3.7? I'm still on Python 3.6 myself.

Comment: Can you provide both input you are passing to reproduce the issue?

Comment: /prac  python3
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43)

Comment: I input "5 3 \n 1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: Try by casting your var first. ```N = int(N) and K = int(K)``` inside addarr method

Comment: sure I alread it ..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it.

One is change `arr.append(score[i])`  to  `arr.append(int(score[i]))`.

Another is to uncomment this line `# arr=[int(x) for x in arr]` in the following code.

```py
import numpy

def addarr(N,K,score):
    arr=[]
    a=10000
    this = int(N)-int(K)+1

    for j in range(0,this):
        for i in range(j,j+int(K)):
            arr.append(int(score[i]))
            print(i)
        print("asdfasdfasdfasfasdf")
        print(arr)
        # The next line can trun ['1', '2', '3'] to [1,2,3]
        # arr=[int(x) for x in arr]
        b = numpy.std(arr)
        print('b=',b)
        if a>b:
            a=b
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NandK = input()
    N, K = NandK.split()

    string = input()
    score =[]
    score = string.split()
    print(score)

    print(len(score))
    answer = addarr(N,K,score)
    print(answer)
```